# #1045 - Access denied

Tags: mysql-error-1064

MySQL said:

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

mysqli_real_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: You sure the password is correct?